# Groovy: Compare float values and find out greater value

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have a float value and a list of float values where I want to compare the float value with list and find out the greater value than the float value and greater than the whole number of the float value with the list.

Eg:

**cv** = `1.5`

**av** = `[1.1,1.5,1.7,1.9,1.11,2.1,2.5]`

***Current code :***

```
versions = av.findAll {
def isVersionGreater
it.indexed().any { i, v ->
if (cv[i] == v) return false
isVersionGreater = v > (cv[i] ?: 0)
return true
}
return isVersionGreater
}
versions.removeAll { it[0] > cv[0] }
versions.collect { it.join('.') }
```

which prints `[1.7,1.9,1.11]`, but I don't want the value with `1`, I want to compare and find out only `[2.1,2.5]` not the other values.

Note: I am collecting the variables av and cv as below

```
av = output2.tokenize().collect { it.tokenize('.').collect { it as int } } 

cv = output.tokenize().collect { it.tokenize('.').collect { it as int } }.first()
```

Could someone help me to achieve this using groovy?

Comment: show the value examples for output and output2 and provide corresponding expected result.

Comment: Output = [1.5] output2 = [1.1,1.5,1.7,1.9,1.11,2.1,2.5]. Cv=[1,5], av = [1,1][1,5][1,7][1,11][2,1][2,5]. I want to fetch only [2.1,2.5] from output2. I have pasted my current output in the question

Comment: You said `cv = 1.5` and then later said `cv[i] == v`.  The `cv[i]` is suspect.  Is `cv` a `String` or a `Number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<=` instead of `>`:

```
versions.removeAll { it[0] <= cv[0] }
print versions.collect { it.join('.') }
```

It means remove all from `it` where its first value is less or equal to first value of `cv`.

Output:

```
[2.1, 2.5]
```

Comment: You're just awesome